# Text field with right aligned background image - auto expandable

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextfield, ios7

I have created a text field using the story board in Xcode 5 - I have applied a background and applied text to the field - but the brief requires the background to expand according to the length of the containing text (the text is a persons name - as shown below )

[image]

Is it possible to auto expand the width based on the content size?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `-sizeToFit` method .